# Should I install IE updates on Windows 8.1 even when IE is disabled in Control Panel?

Tags: windows-8.1, internet-explorer

I have eliminated Internet Explorer and gone to Google Chrome. Is Internet Explorer still lurking somewhere and do I still have to use Internet Explorer security updates?

Comment: Are you referring to Windows Explorer or Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you still need to install the updates because 3rd party tools use IE components like the mshtml.dll to display HTML websites. Not installing the updates could cause security issues in the 3rd party tools.

Comment: In addition, other Windows binaries use IE to host HTML content.  Also, IE relies on system components that might need to be updated. If you look at the details of a few IE updates, you'll realize there's more to the package than just iexplore.exe.